# Links from require_once broken

Tags: php, html

I have a menu file that i want to include in every file of my site to avoid writing every time the same code. I do this with require_once("menu.php"); The problem is that when i click on a link generated by menu.php it results to be a relative link instead, because it doesn't find the file.
This is my directory:

[image]

menu.php:

```
 <?php echo'
 <div class="topnav-bar">
 <ul class="topnav">
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="index.php">Home</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="geografia.php">Geografia</a></li>
      <li><a href="clima.php">Clima</a></li>
      <li><a href="storia.php">Storia</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="pages/luoghi.php">Luoghi</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a href="pages/luoghi/chiesette.php">7 Chiesette</a></li>
      <li><a href="pages/luoghi/catajo.php" class="active">
       Castello del Catajo</a></li>
      <li><a href="pages/luoghi/praglia.php">Abbazia di Praglia</a></li>
      <li><a href="pages/luoghi/carrareseeste.php">
       Castello carrarese di Este</a></li>
      <li><a href="pages/luoghi/lispida.php">Castello di Lispida</a></li>
      <li><a href="pages/luoghi/pelagio.php">Castello San Pelagio</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
    <li class="icon">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="menuMobile()">&#9776;</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>'; ?>
```

if from "index.php" i click on "chiesette.php" for example, the browser shows me the url http://127.0.0.1/pages/luoghi/chiesette.php. Now if from this page i click on "catajo.php" it shows me http://127.0.0.1/pages/luoghi/pages/luoghi/catajo.php.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Add slashes at the beginning of each of your links, so that it will start from the root instead of the current directory. Just make sure you add in the full path to the files.

Comment: Change relative pathes to absolute by adding a slash before pages/ like this: `<a href="/pages/luoghi/chiesette.php">`

Comment: @Alexey That's actually `root-relative URL`, absolute usually have protocol in them.

Comment: putting slash was my solution that used to work on my machine, but a problem arised because my team mate is using windows (i'm using manjaro) and links don't work for him. We are both using apache2.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in *index.php* you are at the root so the link will refers to the right location.
From */pages/luoghi* because of the lack of slash, it builds the link from you actual directory, eg */pages/luoghui*

```
<li><a href="/pages/luoghi/chiesette.php">7 Chiesette</a></li>
  <li><a href="/pages/luoghi/catajo.php" class="active">
   Castello del Catajo</a></li>
  <li><a href="/pages/luoghi/praglia.php">Abbazia di Praglia</a></li>
  <li><a href="/pages/luoghi/carrareseeste.php">
   Castello carrarese di Este</a></li>
  <li><a href="/pages/luoghi/lispida.php">Castello di Lispida</a></li>
  <li><a href="/pages/luoghi/pelagio.php">Castello San Pelagio</a></li>
```

THe code above (whith slashes) should work because the link will be build from root.

Comment: putting slash was my solution that used to work on my machine, but a problem arised because my team mate is using windows (i'm using manjaro) and links didn't work for him. We are both using apache2.